# Ionic Capacitor Cordova YouTube Video Player where to declare YouTubeDataApiKey in Android project

Tags: android, ionic-framework, youtube, capacitor

I am using latest Ionic, Capacitor, and Angular along with https://github.com/ihadeed/CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer to play videos. This is working fine on iOS platform, but I cannot determine where to declare YouTubeDataApiKey in Android project, as required.

In documentation for non-Capacitor project it's defined as this:
`<preference name="YouTubeDataApiKey" value="[YOUR YOUTUBE API]" />`

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to get my Ionic Capacitor project working with [cordova youtube video player](https://github.com/ihadeed/CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer)

In Android project:
Add `<preference name="YouTubeDataApiKey" value="my_youtube_api_key" />` to app/src/main/res/xml/config.xml.

Add `<string name="activity_name">my_bundle_id</string>` to app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml.

Where `my_bundle_id` is like `io.ionic.starter`.

Comment: Not working for me. I have the Youtube app installed and its working on cordova project. But when I try with capacitor project. The following error pops up on a blank black screen. Please help!! 
"Get Youtube App"
"This app won't run without the youtube app, which is missing from your device."

Comment: @Sandy any solution for this , for me also same thing happening